# highcharts, highstock without jQuery

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I understand you can use:

`$(element).highcharts("StockChart", {})` to get a chart on that element.

However, I'd like to either be able to get gold of the `highchart` object so I can manipulate it afterwards, or I'd like to do:

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart : {
      renderTo : 'container'
      type     : 'StockChart'
    }
    ...
  });
```

**Firstly**: The latter does not work for type 'StockChart'. I get [error code 17](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17) which says:

> "The requested series type does not exist"

**Secondly**: I'd prefer to set the `renderTo` option to an element **rather than an id**. By using an id it forces my element to also use an id, but where I can have a container and a `subelement` in it, it becomes hard to reference that.

**Now**, if you have many graphs on a single html page, id's are not ideal. Rather I would like to use the actual **dom element to pass.**

By using `$(element).highcharts("StockChart", {})` I was able to set almost all other options as global ones, including the `rangeSelector` and get things to work.

However, I still need to be able to access `this`, which is available in event functions, such as load, so I guess I could set a global one, but that might be a bit overkill.

Comment: You can use **`var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({});`**. As for the dom element, I don't think it would be possible.

Comment: @RaeenHashemi Thanks! Seem like it was possible, althouhg I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see three questions in your case:

1) To get object when creating chart, you have two ways:

- with jQuery:

  ```
  var chart = $(element).highcharts('StockChart', options).highcharts();
  ```
- without jQuery:

  ```
  var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
  ```

2) Error #17:

> "The requested series type does not exist"

Is caused by `type     : 'StockChart'`. `type` is reserved for a series type. As **@Raeen Hashemi** said, to create Highstock, use different constructor: `new Highcharts.StockChart(options)`.

3) Yes, you can pass an object to `renderTo`: http://jsfiddle.net/yvxwa6oq/

```
new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0] 
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: [10, 20]
    }]
});
```

4) `this` - honestly, I'm not sure why you need access to `this` somewhere else than event handlers. Instead use `Highcharts.charts[index]` or stored variables like `chart` or `$(element).highcharts()`

Answer (score 1):

for ES6, use it in below method.

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as highchartsTree from 'highcharts/modules/treemap';
```

also, any highchart type can be added instead of treemap

```
highchartsTree(Highcharts);
```